# JSON column in Redshift: alternative to jsonb_each?

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

I am moving my database tables from postgres to Redshift and the following query no longer works:

```
select dr.id, dr.opportunity_id, dr.roi -> 'data' ->> 'campaignName' as campaign_Name,
users.value ->> 'name' as influencer_name, users.value ->> 'id' as influencer_dyzio_id, 
users.value -> 'instagramCount' as instagram_Count, users.value -> 'instagramEngagementFactor' as instagram_Engagement_Factor,
users.value -> 'emv' ->> 'estimatedImpressions' as emv_estimated_Impressions,
users.value -> 'emv' ->> 'impressionsCPM' as emv_impressions_CPM,
users.value -> 'emv' ->> 'engagementsCPM' as emv_engagements_CPM, 
users.value ->> 'platformID' as platform_ID
FROM platform_db.dyzio_rois dr, jsonb_each(roi -> 'data' -> 'reportData') as users
```

How can I make it work using Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

Since Redshift doesn't have a native json data type there will be no equivalent function to jsonb_each() in Redshift SQL that will work in all cases AFAIK.  Use-case specific Redshift SQL may be possible in some cases and UDFs may be workable in others.  More information on source data and expected results will be needed to provide help on generating a solution for your use-case.

Redshift supports json stored as text and has functions to extract information from these strings.  json_extract_path_text() is one such function that will extract text values based on the json keys used in the string.  This is structured as one string (of json) per row in the table.  Since you are working in Redshift I assume you have stored your json as strings this way.  jsonb_each() in Postgres expands elements from a json blob into rows of data.  Expanding rows based on elements in json-storing-text columns is possible but you may want to think about your data model and why you are storing multiple "rows" of data within a json text column (roi -> 'data' -> 'reportData').  Doing this will be slow and hard to query.